# Where should I add my own Markdown file in Vapor project?

Tags: swift, xcode, nsbundle, vapor

I want to add my own Markdown file, a file named `profile.md`. However, I don't know where I should add the file in my Vapor project, which is developed in Xcode.

I tried adding it to `Sources/` or just the root directory, but it cannot be searched by `Bundle.main.url(forResource:)` function, like:

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "profile", withExtension: ".md") else { ... }
```

Also, I found that I already added it under *Copy Bundle Resources* tab.

In the normal app (for iOS and macOS), the function above works properly.

How can I add my own file to be used in Vapor project developed in Xcode?

Comment: Vapor uses a different structure to an app bundle. What did you want to do with this Markdown file, serve it as-is, parse it, interpret it as a template file?

Comment: @tobygriffin I just want to read the file, parse, and embed it into another template file to return to the user.

Comment: @Blaszard did you get this figured out? The other commenters are correct, just load the file and return. I want to mention that I don't believe `Bundle` apis are available on Linux. You'll have to do a bit more of a manual lookup as you would a macos file or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *very basic* example of loading the contents of a file from a custom location using Foundation rather than Vapor's template view loading mechanism, and returning it as a text response.

```
drop.get { req in
  let templateString = try String(contentsOfFile: drop.workDir + "Resources/profile.md")
  return templateString
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "parse, and embed it into another template file" but you'd put that bit in between the lines above.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm not sure why the use of Bundle fails, though. Is it not working for a project like Vapor?

Comment: That's right. A Bundle is a macOS-specific folder format that wraps a binary executable along with various other resources to represent an application. Vapor, on macOS and on Linux, simply produces the binary executable and therefore has no concept of a Bundle.